# php PDF generation

Tags: php

I have got a new task.I am generating a pdf in php.So can any one help me out how to move ahead.i have gone through php manual there i got some help about generating pdf.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which is the best PDF library for PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560583/which-is-the-best-pdf-library-for-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560583/which-is-the-best-pdf-library-for-php. PHP does not have built-in support for the PDF format, so you will have to use a library.